# error authenaticating sql database from python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to run this code:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

import mysql.connector
import csv
import pandas as pd

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  user="root",
  passwd="abc123",
  database="db"

)
```

But I am receiving this **error**:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\user123\Desktop\SQLtest\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        passwd="abc123",

    .
    .
    .
 "Authentication plugin '{0}' is not supported".format(plugin_name))
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears because MySQL 8 uses [caching_sha2_password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html) as the default authentication plugin rather than mysql_native_password.

To solve this issue, try adding `auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'` to your connection parameters - to make your connection uses the native authentication plugin - as below:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  user="root",
  passwd="abc123",
  database="db",
  auth_plugin="mysql_native_password"
)
```

Comment: I tried that, but still getting this error: `"Authentication plugin '{0}' is not supported".format(plugin_name))
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported`

Comment: Can you try using mysql-connector-python instead of mysql-connector? install it via pip, e.g: `pip install mysql-connector-python`

Comment: I created a new database and connected to it and now it works? Thanks for your help anyway